# MVC3...Save the model any time a View is unloaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, navigation, save

I have a C#.NET web app and would like to save my underlying Model anytime the user navigates off a View.  I am using the .Net Entity Framework witha DbContext object.  How would I implement a Save on Navigation?

Comment: `Page_Unload` has *absolutely nothing whatsoever* to do with a user navigating away from your page.

Comment: That happens on the client.  You need to learn about Javascript and client-server programming.

Comment: Page_Unload in a webforms app in the code behind page.....

Comment: `Page_Unload` in a **WebForms** app does *not* do what you think it does. Not at all. It runs when the page is done being processed and is being unloaded from the server, *before* it is sent to the client. It has *absolutely nothing* to do with the client navigating away from the page.

Comment: @Andrew...can you help with the question?

Comment: @MikeTWebb - SLaks is right, you need to do it client-side. And even then it's not 100% reliable. Rethink your design. Why not save when actions are performed that need to update the model? Time-based persistence is not a good idea IMO.

Comment: @RPM...thank for the feedback. Yeah, I was using actions to Save...but the users want to navigate anywhere in the app and have data saved. I suppose I could submit the View on any potential action, thereby saving the data. But that seems un-wieldy

Comment: @MikeTWebb - this is holdover from desktop application thinking.  Web apps are not desktop apps, and they operate in a fundamentally different way.  You need to design apps so that user data is saved progressively, rather than all-at-once.  The best you can hope for is like what Stack Overflow does, and pop up a dialog when data is dirty.

Comment: @MikeTWebb That's what I was trying to tell you with the Page_Unload thing; you can't do it like that.

Comment: I agree with all of the above. You will need to design your model update logic using ajax where any activity on the page (displayed page view) is saved to server immediately.
If you can provide an example for the form, we can help you with coming up with ajaxified action method and client-side logic

Comment: @Roman...I would love to see an ajaxified example....not sure what code you'dlike to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All....thanks for the comments.  It was educational.  Using the info provided regarding forms and posts, I used  buttons to do poast and investigated their valuse to decide what action to perform.

On the Views that had navigation links, I swapped in the input buttons and used CSS to make them look and act like hyperlinks.
                
and

```
        <input style="width:40px;" 
            class="navigate_save_header" 
            type="submit" name="NavSave" 
            value="Delete SubTask"
        />
```

The Task Controller has "NavSave" as a parameter into the Edit [POST]....and the value is either "Create SubTask" or "Delete SubTask".  In the controller, I check if "NavSave" is null or not....if not, I then examine the value.  If "Create SubTask", I save the Task Model and navigate to the  Subtask Create[GET] method.  If "DeleteSubTask", I save the Task Model and navigate to the Subtask Delete[GET] method.  In order to do this, I also have a hidden field containing the SubTask id....so when I Navigate to the Delete[Get] method, I know which SubTask to delete.

Give comments if you like...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make periodically "saves" via ajax, so once the user leaves the page, it has all saved.